# NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: computing wrong height

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, uilabel, sizewithfont

I have a Subtitle style UITableViewCell which height changes dynamically depending on the length of the text for each field. The problem is that the textLabel's height (CGSize size) does not increase if the label has multiple lines.

[image: http://s10.postimg.org/6urher7s9/text_Label.png]

The weird part is that the detailTextLabel's height is increasing as it should (CGSize size2). The code to calculate both heights are identical.

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/m0af4gyw7/detail.png]

Here is my function:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SETLISTFMNS0Song *song = [[[selectedSetlist.sets objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] songs]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [song.name sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:setlistFont size:labelFontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.setsTable.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    NSLog(@"Label: \"%@\" \tLabel Size: %f W %f H", song.name, size.width, size.height);

    NSMutableString *detail;
    if ([song cover]) {
        detail = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"(%@ cover)", [[song cover] name]];
    }
    if ([song with]) {
        if (!detail) {
            detail = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"(with %@)", [[song with] name]];
        }
        else {
            [detail appendFormat:@" (with %@)", [[song with] name]];
        }
    }
    if ([song info]) {
        if (!detail) {
            detail = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"(%@)", [song info]];
        }
        else {
            [detail appendFormat:@" (%@)", [song info]];
        }
    }

    if (detail.length != 0) {
        CGSize size2 = [detail sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:setlistFont size:detailFontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.setsTable.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
        size.height += size2.height;
        NSLog(@"Detail Label: \"%@\" \tDetail Label Size: %f W %f H", detail, size2.width, size2.height);
    }

    return size.height + 5;
}
```

I am also setting both textLabel's numberOfLines property to 0 in cellForRowAtIndexPath to support multiple lines:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @josh I now understand why this is happening. I had the width constraints set to the width of the UITableView, which is too wide. Anyone know how to find the width of the UILabel before it is created? HA!

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the image links and somebody will take care of them for you.

Comment: @A-Live Thanks for the idea. Images are now uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long are the strings you're calculating the size against? I ask because you're `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` function is constraining to the full width of the cell, but your labels are probably not the full width of the cell.

What I suspect is happening is `song.info` is just short enough that it would fit on one line if the line were the full width of the cell, and that your song `detail` is long enough that it is calculating the correct number of lines, but not so long as to exceed the calculated height.

All of that to say, I think what you need to do is find out the widths of `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` and set your constraints to those values.

**Update - A way of calculating label widths**

Since the width of the labels inside of a cell are dependent on the width of the cell, and since cell's aren't created at the time `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, we need to come up with a way to know the labels' widths before they the widths are set. The only way to do this is to set the widths ourselves. Here's how I would do it:

MyCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

+ (CGFloat)textLabelWidthForCellOfWidth:(CGFloat)cellWidth;

@end
```

MyCell.m

```
#import "MyCell.h"

@implementation MyCell

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = self.textLabel.frame;
    frame.size.width = [MyCell textLabelWidthForCellOfWidth:self.frame.size.width];
    self.textLabel.frame = frame;
}

+ (CGFloat)textLabelWidthForCellOfWidth:(CGFloat)cellWidth {
    // This calculation can be as complex as necessary to account for all elements that affect the label
    return cellWidth - 20;
}

@end
```

Then in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation you can call the same class method:

```
CGFloat labelWidth = [MyCell textLabelWidthForCellOfWidth:self.tableView.frame.size.width]; // Since non-grouped cells are the full width of the tableView
CGSize size2 = [detail sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:setlistFont size:detailFontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

You would create a separate Class Method (+) for each label that you need to reference.

Comment: The strings for textLabel aren't long at all, for they are song titles, but the font size for the textLabel is 26.0 right now so they appear large. I changed the constraint width to the width of the textLabel, but heightForRowAtIndexpath gets called before the textLabel is created (creating a runtime error) so I don't think there's a way of accessing the width without hardcoding it? Unless you have any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately you're right. Hard coding the values is your simplest option. You could subclass `UITableViewCell` and create class methods that return the appropriate widths and then use those class methods in both `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (or in the `layoutSubviews` method of your subclass), but that may be more work than is necessary to do what you're wanting. I'd start with hard coding and grow from there.

Comment: I think your initial theory is correct. When I have song titles that are pretty long, they seem to correctly resize. I will try to find a way to access the width of the textLabel, hopefully without subclassing uitableviewcell.

Comment: @AUSTOOO I'm not sure if you found a solution yet, but I just read about one way of doing it. Basically you load the table, and the first time through you don't know the widths of the cells at the time it calcs heights, but you can store the widths of the labels in an IVAR during cellForRow... and then call reloadData again, and this time you have the widths. I don't much like it, but it's a solution.

Comment: Currently I am hardcoding it, but would like to avoid this if possible. Could you possibly send me a link? I am curious how they implement it. I don't want to call reloadData every time a new cell is about to appear (ex. scrolling)

Comment: @AUSTOOO I can't find the link again, but I've updated the answer with what I think is a better solution anyway. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Although I am not understanding why you need to subclass UITableViewCell. It seems that the class method can be implemented from within my class file. What is the advantage to overriding layoutSubviews?

Comment: I now understand that usefulness in subclassing UITabelViewCell. However I cannot get layoutSubviews to be called. Do you know how to invoke layoutSubviews?

Comment: Nevermind! I think i figured it out! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

as looking at your code i found you are missing to define "lineBreakMode".

```
CGSize theSize = [song.name sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:setlistFont size:labelFontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.setsTable.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

update your code with this. i hope it will fix your problem. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also tried that previously with no success.

Comment: have you set lineBreakMode for UILable?

Comment: Specifically for UILabel? No. At the time I call this method the label has not been created yet.

Comment: then set it for specifically for label, lineBreakMode should be same for your label as well, size calculataion, otherwise output may vary.

Comment: the label itself is correctly breaking, even without assigning a value to the linebreak property. The issue is that when the label necessitates a second line, the height isn't adjusting accordingly.